# Need cheap (inexpensive) GPU for desktop PC

Tags: graphics-cards

Needs to support 1440p@100Hz. No gaming will be involved. Lowest possible price and consumption. Monitor has both HDMI and DP.

Comment: You should tell us what it *does* need to run, "no gaming" isn't enough information to qualify a GPU for you. Also does the monitor have HDMI 2.0 or do you really need DP to run 1440p @ 100hz?

Comment: What OS are you using? Drivers (and ongoing support) may be a limiting factor here, not just hardware. Also, can you provide the specific monitor you're using? I'm guessing you need HDMI 2.0 or DisplayPort 1.2, but it depends.

Comment: Monitor has same specs on both HDMI and DP, so whichever works.

Comment: Can you provide the exact model number anyways? Sometimes there are interesting quirks. Also what OS are you using?

Comment: Found RX 550 for 30 EUR. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What other type of hardware is the rest of the PC and what are you trying to accomplish? Because instead of a dedicated GPU an APU from Ryzen might get the job done for cheaper and efficiently.

Comment: That was the other idea, but didn't want to mess with CPU compatibility and MoBo, unless this failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a GTX 1660 Super or RTX 3050Ti

Comment: Much cheaper, like 10x preferably. For that kind of money I can get a whole new PC.

Answer (score 0):

I would say GT 710 but that one doesn't have displayport so I had to look further, and just a small bit further I found the MSI GT 1030, which can now be found for €90. It has one DP and one HDMI, has such a low power consumtion that it doesn't need dedicated PSU power and has passive cooling. It's not 10x cheaper than the 1660 super but it's the cheapest I could find before I had to get to the bus

Comment: Something used maybe? I just need GPU to put the picture out. For 60€ I can get a a Ryzen 3400G. I never though finding a normal 40€ pixel-thrower would be such a problem.

Comment: If you want something used I can't help you with the prices since those vary even more than new. If you do want something used, maybe you can find an RX 550?

Comment: Yep, nice suggestion. RX 550 seems like a good fit. Thanks.